# export pdf cuts of small part of transparent line

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export, transparency

I made a logo with 5 leaves. Two of them are transparent. When I export it as a .png, it's good. But when I export it as a .pdf the line of the 2 leaves are cut.

I experimented a bit and this only happens when I turn the leaves diagonal and when the lines are transparent. If the stroke is not transparent or the leave is horizontal or vertical than everything is good.

Someone who can help me, I would really appreciate :)

[image]

Comment: May I suggest that you mention the software used, and if possible use the adequate tag.

Comment: adobe illustrator cc 2017 :)

Comment: What PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: ahh, thats the solution probably. I use foxit reader, in pdf reader and adobe acrobat the problem isn't there. This took me hours haha, thanks problem solved.

Comment: @Veugerton Why don't you write that as an answer, then you can accept your own answer as best answer. It might help others avoid spending "hours" trying to figure out what's wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Foxit Reader gave me these cuts in the transparant stroke of the leaves. Other PDF readers didn't have that problem!